# VueJS: Passing child method to parent doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here, the parent is passing `name` & `age` props to child. The child component emits a custom event `changeAgeFn` that passes its `changeAge` method to parent.

In the parent, the (passed) `changeAge` event is attached to click event on `button[change age]`.

However this way does not work. I would like the know the standard/recommended way to executing child event from parent.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="parent-wrap">
        <p>UserName: {{user}}, age: {{age}}
        <button @click="changeAge()"> Change Age</button></p>
        <child :user="user" :age="age" @userChanged="user = $event" @changeAgeFn="$event" ></child>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import child from './child.vue'

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                user: 'John',
                age: 35
            }
        },
        components: {
            child
        },        
    }
</script>

<style>
.child-wrap {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.parent-wrap {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="child-wrap">
        <p>UserName: {{user}}, age: {{age}}
        <button @click="changeName"> Change Name</button></p>
    </div>
</template> 

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user', 'age'],
        methods: {
            changeName() {
                this.user = 'Rahul'
                this.$emit('userChanged', this.user)
                this.$emit('changeAgeFn', this.changeAge)
            },
            changeAge() {
                this.age = '20'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a bit confused here. You need to inject changeAge as a prop to the child component from the parent so that it updates the state of the parent and this triggers a re-render of child.

So your child needs a prop with the following signature:

```
changeAge: () => void
```

You then define changeAge in the parent:

```
// parent, NOT child 
methods: {
    ...
    changeAge() {
            this.age = '20'
        }
...
```

}

And then inject it into child:

```
<template>
    ...
    <child :changeAge=“changeAge” etc.../>
    ...
</template>
```

Hope that helps.